# How can i add a field to upload account picture in salesforce

Tags: account

I have seen a image like field in the account detail page , but it says to add the picture thru some social account. Is there any possibility to add a field to upload a picture and show it in the account detail page.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This requirement seems like [Display Picture in Contact](http://forceguru.blogspot.in/2011/06/display-picture-in-contact.html)

In this post a complete solution is provided to add picture on any object detail page.

You only need to change logic in `DisplayImagesController` class and its page as you are fetching details from social site. Some integration need to be done.

If you face some problem you can post/comment your problem here.

Answer (score 3):

There are two free AppExchange packages that will do this well:

- [Salesforce Labs' Picture Uploader](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000001TKzOEAW)
- [MK Partners' Photo Uploader](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000001TKzOEAW)

The other, even simpler alternative is to add a [Rich-Text custom field](https://na2.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/fields_using_rich_text_area.htm) to the object in question. I don't think you can restrict it to only photos, though, so the user-training hurdle might be a bit higher.